# UnableToDeserializePostBody while trying to create Event in Calendar

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I am currently trying to create a python script, that can create new events in my calendar. Here's what I do to send the request :

```
async def send_events(activity, email):
    #Request to the API, creating a new calendar event
    request_body = Event()
    request_body.subject = activity[0].split(' ', 1)

    body = ItemBody()
    body.content_type = BodyType.Html

    body.content = activity[0]

    request_body.body = body
    start = DateTimeTimeZone()
    start.date_time = activity[1]

    start.time_zone = 'Europe/Paris'

    request_body.start = start
    end = DateTimeTimeZone()
    end.date_time = activity[2]

    end.time_zone = 'Europe/Paris'

    request_body.end = end
    location = Location()
    location.display_name = 'not available'

    request_body.location = location
    attendees_attendee1 = Attendee()
    attendees_attendee1email_address = EmailAddress()
    attendees_attendee1email_address.address = email

    attendees_attendee1email_address.name = activity[4] + ' ' + activity[5]

    attendees_attendee1.email_address = attendees_attendee1email_address
    attendees_attendee1.type = AttendeeType.Required

    attendeesArray = [attendees_attendee1]
    request_body.attendees = attendeesArray

    request_body.allow_new_time_proposals = True

    request_body.is_online_meeting = False

    request_configuration = EventsRequestBuilder.EventsRequestBuilderPostRequestConfiguration(
    headers = {
        'Prefer' : "outlook.timezone=\"Europe/Paris\"",
    }

    )
    client.me.events.get()
    result = await client.me.events.post(body = request_body, request_configuration = request_configuration)
```

I keep receiving this error.

`msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error.ODataError: APIError 400: None MainError(additional_data={}, code='UnableToDeserializePostBody', details=None, inner_error=None, message='were unable to deserialize ', target=None)`

I am using python 3.11.14 and msgraph-sdk 1.0.0a14

I have tried a lot of different versions of both python and the msgraph-sdk.
I am also using trio instead of asyncio for asynchronous functions because there are known issues between msgraph and asyncio.

Thanks a lot for any info ! I am really stuck.